# styling a <label> inside a <p> inside a <div>

Tags: html, css

I am having some problems styling an AJAX callback message box. As you can see the styling works well in Internet Explorer but not in Chrome. I can not see the wood for the trees, so to speak. Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="CallbackMessage">
    <p>
        <label id="uiLblCallbackErrMsg" class="CallbackMsg" runat="server">&nbsp</label>
    </p>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.CallbackErrorMessage
{
    margin: 0 25 4 20;
    height: 10px;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:12px;
    background-color: #FDC68A;
    border: 1px solid #F7977A;
    color: Red;    
}
```

Using jQuery I add the class `CallbackErrorMessage` to the `<div id="CallbackMessage">` when pushing the button!

I'm not able to see the error, any advice is appreciated.

Have a look at the two images:

[image]

[image]

Comment: _"As you can see"_, no we can't see. What exactly is the problem? What's the JS you're using?

Comment: `margin: 0 25 4 20;` should be `margin: 0 25px 4px 20px;`

Comment: `&nbsp` should be `&nbsp;`

Comment: others already replied. i want to tell you another thing. it is better if you don't use many classes or divs, try to keep the code as simpler as possible. For example instead of creating a new class you may add new properties to an existing class. this is a general suggestion anyway it depends on what you have on your mind. Try to optimise the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling the class name is totally wrong. You are using `id="CallbackMessage"` in your html and writing style for `.CallbackErrorMessage`

Change the css like this,

```
    #CallbackMessage
{
    margin: 4px 25px 4px 20px;
    height: auto; padding:10px;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:12px;
    background-color: #FDC68A;
    border: 1px solid #F7977A;
    color: Red; 
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/JE2By/4/)

Comment: He is adding the class dynamically with JQuery

Comment: @Matanya that he hadn't mentioned at the first time. Anyways except that also this css works.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Not having errors doesn't mean it's useful. It completely changes the purpose of the code and ignores the fact that the class is being added using jQuery. The very first sentence in the answer is absolutely incorrect.

Comment: The answer is incorrect - see OP: "Using jQuery I add the class CallbackErrorMessage to the <div class="CallbackMessage"> when pushing the button!"

Comment: @AnthonyGrist and Matanya, This answer is posted even before the OP mention (Edited question) the fact of the jquery class adding.

Comment: @Sowmya The very first revision of the question mentions that the class is being added using jQuery from what I can see in the revision history.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist if you observe the timing it is even before that and i havnt edited my answer. and he might have got the idea of adding the fact of jquery after looking at the answers coz this was mentioned in praveen's answer too.

Comment: @Sowmya, be it as it may. Why aren't you deleting\revising it, now that you know it does not answer to OP's question?

Comment: Answers are not meant to be revised based on the edited (not-clear) question. Anyways I don't wanna go through dumb argument. better to end here and this is not place for tat.

Answer (score 6):

#### Error in CSS

```
.CallbackErrorMessage
{
    margin: 0 25 4 20;
    height: 10px;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:12px;
    background-color: #FDC68A;
    border: 1px solid #F7977A;
    color: Red;    
}
```

You left the pixel values for the CSS.

```
margin: 0 25 4 20;
```

Replace the above with:

```
margin: 0 25px 4px 20px;
```

#### You need to clear the floats!

Give an `overflow: hidden;` to the `.CallbackErrorMessage` style.

#### Since you are referencing an `ID` and not a class, it should be:

```
#CallbackErrorMessage
```

#### Issue with `&nbsp;`

And moreover, the `&nbsp` should be replaced with `&nbsp;`. You missed the semicolon.

#### Final CSS

```
#CallbackErrorMessage
{
    margin: 0 25px 4px 20px;
    height: 10px;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:12px;
    background-color: #FDC68A;
    border: 1px solid #F7977A;
    color: Red;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

---

#### Remove `height` from the `#CallbackErrorMessage`

```
height: 10px;
```

Remove it or change it to `height: auto;`.

Comment: Thanks for the advices! I've corrected the minor ones (px and ;) that doesn't have any affect though, but offcourse are standards! @Prumar: Referencing is in order, I am just adding the class to the div jquery-wise. Clearing the floats just removes the text!

Comment: @user1957434 How did you clear the float? Can you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Thanks to all of you, the Height: auto; did the trick!!! IMHO this code is as clean as possible. The idea is to have a div which can make different appearences just adding a class to it, with jquery. I have have three classes I can add separately (ok, info, error) where I offcourse before adding the class removes any other class before that! If this is not clean and simple, please let me know any best practices...!

Comment: Eeeks... No, just remove the height! :)

Comment: That's right, or just use inherit! Do you have a comment on the simpleness of this...?